# Transitive action and elementary abelian 2-group of stabilizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> Show that no subgroup $G$ of $S_5$ acts transitively on $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ in such a way that $G_x$ is an elementary abelian 2-group for any $x\in X$

I want to solve this problem. I decided to use proof by contradiction.

By orbit-stabilizer theorem and with transitive condition, $|X|=|Gx|=|G:G_x|$. Then $|G|=|X||Gx|=5|Gx|$.

By Lagrange theorem with above condition, $|G|$ can be $5, 10, 20, 40$. But there is no progress from here.

Help me how to solve this problem!

Comment: The statement in this form is not correct. The subgroup $D_5$ for example acts with stabilizers of order $2$ (and hence these are automatically elementary abelian). Or the cyclic group of order $5$ for that matter, with trivial stabilizers.

Comment: So $|G|=5$ and $|G|=10$ are possible. If $|G|=20$ or $40$, then $G$ has a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup by Sylow's theorem, and you can get a contradiction by proving that a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $S_5$ is not normalized by and elementary abelian subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  Thank you for advice. My textbook has many wrong problems... TT